# I am developing plugin give following error while activation gives

Tags: wordpress

The plugin generated 2 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, my code is below

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: configuration
Description: example plugin to demonstrate wordpress capatabilities
Author: kailash
License: Public Domain
*/

// run the install scripts upon plugin activation

function test_init() {

    if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $setting=$_POST['setting'];

        global $wpdb;
        $table_name ="setting";
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET setting='$setting' WHERE id=1");
        //echo"Setting Saved";
    }
    ?>

    <form name="form" id="myform"  method="POST">
        <input type="radio" name="setting" value="2" <?php if($setting==2){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> id="term"/>newconfiguration<br>
        <input type="radio" name="setting" value="1" <?php if($setting==1){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> id="term"/>oldconfiguration<br>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="save">
        <?php
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'config_plugin_setup_menu');

function config_plugin_setup_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'Test Plugin Page', 'configuration', 'manage_options', 'config-plugin', 'test_init' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Headers already sent**

It is usually because there are spaces, new lines, or other garbage before an opening `<?php` tag or after a closing `?>`

check and remove all unnecessary space. example check before

`<form>` tag. means after `?>` tag there is extra space in your code. so check other too and remove all space..!

Check that the very first characters are

```
<?php
```

Check that the very last characters are

```
?>
```

for details check this 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Answers-Troubleshooting